# Генерация PDF файлов веб страницы c svg графикой?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, svg, pdf

Какие есть библиотеки которые,  создают `PDF` документ из веб страницы?
Желательно на стороне сервера. Передаешь `URL` адрес и получаешь готовый `PDF` файл.

Что важно:

1. Все прокручиваемые элементы на странице должны раскрываться и попадать в отчёт полностью.
2. На каждой странице pdf должна оставаться шапка(фильтры).
3. PDF должен корректно создавать svg элементы.
4. Страницы PDF не должны обрезаться. Например: если  строки таблицы переносятся, то полностью на новую страницу, а не обрезаются.

Из тех что нашел:
 - `wkhtmltopdf`

Есть ли решения аналогичные `wkhtmltopdf`?

Comment: wkhtmltopdf - лучший. К сожалению.

Comment: Самое корректное создание PDF с веб страницы, это создание его скриншота в последующем его преобразовании в PDF )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можешь посмотреть [`Puppeteer`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/).

### Преимущества `Puppeteer` над `wkhtmltopdf`:

1. Качество рендринга PDF выше (больший вес соответственно)
2. Проще в использовании
3. Использует хорошо поддерживаемое ПО (разработан Google)
4. Использует меньше зависимостей от `Elixir`

### Минусы `Puppeteer` над `wkhtmltopdf`:

1. Нужен `nodeJS`
2. Больший вес файлов (около 90-100 мб)

Решай сам, что тебе больше подходит.

Answer (score 1):

также есть [принц.](https://www.princexml.com/) бесплатный вкорячивает свое лого в пдф.